# error: no matching function for call to const

Tags: c++, constants

My main() want to call

```
program p;   
p.isPath("c9", "c5")
```

program.h has

```
stack<City> isPath(City, City);
```

program.cpp has

```
stack<City> Program::isPath(City originCity, City destCity)
{
        stack<City> flight; // = new Stack<City>();
        originCity.setVisited(true);
        flight.push(originCity);
        checkPath(&originCity, &destCity, &flight);
        return flight;
 }
```

stack of city is created and cities added in stack as:

```
Program::Program()
{
City* c1 = new City("C1");
City* c2 = new City("C2");
City* c3 = new City("C3");
City* c4 = new City("C4");
City* c5 = new City("C5");
City* c6 = new City("C6");
City* c7 = new City("C7");
City* c8 = new City("C8");
City* c9 = new City("C9");
Program::found = true;

list<City>* allCities = new list<City>();
this->allCities->push_back(*c1);this->allCities->push_back(*c2); this->allCities->push_back(*c3);allCities->push_back(*c4); this->allCities->push_back(*c5);
this->allCities->push_back(*c6); this->City destCityallCities->push_back(*c7); this->allCities->push_back(*c8); this->allCities->push_back(*c9);

c1->addCityToCities(c7);
c1->addCityToCities(c2);
c2->addCityToCities(c3);
c3->addCityToCities(c4);
c4->addCityToCities(NULL);
c5->addCityToCities(c7);
c6->addCityToCities(c5);c7->addCityToCities(c6); c7->addCityToCities(c8);c8->addCityToCities(c2); c8->addCityToCities(c9);c9->addCityToCities(c6);
```

City class has following code:

```
City::City()
{
list<City>* cities = new list<City>();
}
City::City(string _name){
  this->name = _name;
  list<City>* cities = new list<City>();
  visited = false;
```

I am having this error message

```
main.cpp:  error: no matching function for call to 'Program::isPath(const char [3], const char [3])'
main.cpp:  note: candidate is:
\include\Program.h: note: std::stack<City> Program::isPath(City, City)
\include\Program.h: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'const char [3]' to 'City'
```

This is travelling salesman application. Could anybody help me resolve this error please.

Comment: I'll bet you none of those pointers are doing you any good.

Comment: Note isPath takes a copy of the city, so any changes to the parameter will not alter the original city.

Comment: Elaborate on `class City;` declaration please. I'd guess you're violating the [rule of 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) or providing an appropriate conversion constructor.

Comment: my city class has following code : please see extra added code

Comment: C++ is not Java. `list<City>* allCities = new list<City>();` is wrong. It should be `list<City> allCities;` Same with all your cities. They don't need new and pointers.

Comment: It is also bad form to have a method named something such as `isPath()` modify its operands: the method and its parameters should all be `const`.

Comment: @JohnGaughan Technically it only modifies copies of the parameters so it's ok (although I don't know if the OP intended that)

Answer (score 2):

Your code has many problems, but the one you asked about is this:

```
program p;   
p.isPath("c9", "c5")
```

Assuming "program" is "Program", the `isPath` function takes two `City` parameters, not two strings. You will need to pass City objects, or change the type of the parameters.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I am new to c++. But, c9, c5 are not the city names, these are the city objects. because, in program.cpp, i have done
    city*c9 = new city(C9);
can you please suggest on it...

Comment: @ShasiPokharel Remove the quotes, as this makes them strings.